# Add link to entire column with appsscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm retrieving information from an API and have to link the ID to the website.

I have the following code that is working but right now I'm retrieving 150 results and are expecting to have over 650. With 150 it takes two minutes to iterate through the API call and this `for`.

```
  for (var i = 2; i <= count; i++) {
    var forRange = sheet.getRange("A"+i)
    var forValue = forRange.getValue();
    const richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
        .setText(forValue)
        .setLinkUrl('https://link.com/view.php?id=' + forValue)
        .build();
    forRange.setRichTextValue(richText);
  }
```

My question is: Is there a more optimized way to do this iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, `getValue()` and `setRichTextValue()` are used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. I think that this is the reason for your issue. In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); // Please use your Sheet object here.

const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
const values = range.getDisplayValues();
const obj = range.getRichTextValues().map(([a], i) => [a.copy().setText(values[i][0]).setLinkUrl('https://link.com/view.php?id=' + values[i][0]).build()]);
range.setRichTextValues(obj);
```

- When this script is run, the object of RichTextValue is created for each row as an array. And, the created RichTextValue is used with `setRichTextValues`. By this, I thought that the process cost can be reduced.

#### Note:

- In the current stage, `getRichTextValues()` cannot retrieve the number value from the cells by the current specification. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393310) When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it was found that the values of column "A" are the number values. This is the current issue. So, I modified my proposed script.

#### References:

- [setRichTextValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluesvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: When I try to apply your code all I get is an empty column.

Comment: @Omar Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `When I try to apply your code all I get is an empty column.`, although I modified your showing script, in this case, it is considered that your actual Spreadsheet might be different from your showing script. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to modify my proposed script.

Comment: thank you for responding. My sheet has 2 columns like this document https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZGHo_BbTXs3NnT5LN0WofYpiXZkUoWCN0-p3MIoSU-4/edit?usp=sharing I get the value from the A column and just turn it into a link. I copied the portion of the code straight from appscript editor.

My sheet const is as follows
`const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');`

Comment: @Omar Thank you for replying and providing a sample Spreadsheet. When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, it was found that the values of column "A" are the number values. This is the current issue. So, I modified my proposed script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thank you so much for your help! This has reduced the time of execution by so much!

Comment: @Omar Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.